# Laravel optional parameter in API-request perceived incorrectly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

In my api.php I've these routes.

I can request endpoint: `/api/v2/commodities/1` - this request is being redirected to `APICommodityController@read` - this is OK!

The problem occur whenever I GET-request `/v2/commodities/categories/`. I'd like this request to be redirected into the route-group: 'categories', but instead Laravel perceive this as a optional parameter within the first group (~ ref. "HERE" in code-comment).

How do I fix this?

```
Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'v2' ], function() {

    /**
     * Commodity
     */
    Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'commodities' ], function() {

        /**
         * C: CREATE
         */
        Route::post( '{id?}', 'API\v2\Commodity\APICommodityController@updateOrCreate' );

        /**
         * U: UPDATE
         */
        Route::put( '{id}', 'API\v2\Commodity\APICommodityController@updateOrCreate' );

        /**
         * R: READ (HERE)
         */
        Route::get( '{id?}', 'API\v2\Commodity\APICommodityController@read' );

        /**
         * D: DELETE
         */
        Route::delete( '{id}', 'API\v2\Commodity\APICommodityController@delete' );

        /**
         * Commodity categories
         */
        Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'categories' ], function() {

            /**
             * C: CREATE
             */
            Route::post( '{id?}', 'API\v2\CommodityCategories\APICommodityCategoriesController@updateOrCreate' );

            /**
             * U: UPDATE
             */
            Route::put( '{id}', 'API\v2\CommodityCategories\APICommodityCategoriesController@updateOrCreate' );

            /**
             * R: READ
             */
            Route::get( '{id?}', 'API\v2\CommodityCategories\APICommodityCategoriesController@read' );

            /**
             * D: DELETE
             */
            Route::delete( '{id}', 'API\v2\CommodityCategories\APICommodityCategoriesController@delete' );

        } );

    } );
```

Comment: The priority goes by the order you declare the routes. If you declare the `categories` before the {id} route it should work. If you don't want to do this then you should have a `->where('id', '^\d+$')` regex in your read route to limit the valid inputs

Comment: Just add the categories route before the `{id}` route. since `{}` is a catch all parameter.

Comment: Ye, you might be right about that, but priority (are in my opinion) so easy to mess up. I'd prefer some more realiable solution - if this exist?

Comment: @apokryfos I'll give that a try. One moment

Comment: It seems to work now, thanks (using ->where('id', '^\d+$') )

Comment: Why don't you just use the `ResourceController` feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this condition at the end of your id parameters :

```
->where('id', '[0-9]+')
```

so it becomes something like this :

```
Route::get( '{id?}', 'API\v2\Commodity\APICommodityController@read' )->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply move your Commodity categories route section above all other route definition. This will make laravel register this static route and not be caught by dynamic routing.

Something like that:

```
Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'v2' ], function() {

    /**
     * Commodity
     */
    Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'commodities' ], function() {
        /**
         * Commodity categories
         */
        Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'categories' ], function() {

            /**
             * C: CREATE
             */
            Route::post( '{id?}', 'API\v2\CommodityCategories\APICommodityCategoriesController@updateOrCreate' );

            /**
             * U: UPDATE
             */
            Route::put( '{id}', 'API\v2\CommodityCategories\APICommodityCategoriesController@updateOrCreate' );

            /**
             * R: READ
             */
            Route::get( '{id?}', 'API\v2\CommodityCategories\APICommodityCategoriesController@read' );

            /**
             * D: DELETE
             */
            Route::delete( '{id}', 'API\v2\CommodityCategories\APICommodityCategoriesController@delete' );

        } );

        /**
         * C: CREATE
         */
        Route::post( '{id?}', 'API\v2\Commodity\APICommodityController@updateOrCreate' );

        /**
         * U: UPDATE
         */
        Route::put( '{id}', 'API\v2\Commodity\APICommodityController@updateOrCreate' );

        /**
         * R: READ (HERE)
         */
        Route::get( '{id?}', 'API\v2\Commodity\APICommodityController@read' );

        /**
         * D: DELETE
         */
        Route::delete( '{id}', 'API\v2\Commodity\APICommodityController@delete' );
    } );
```